# Ubuntu Image Background breaking after build LiveCD

Tags: 14.04, live-usb, live-cd, desktop-background, uck

i'm build a customization Ubuntu using UCK (https://launchpad.net/uck) and using a Image of Ubuntu 14.04.3.

The thing is, i replace the background `warty-final-ubuntu.png` in `/usr/share/backgrounds` for a another image, where this is image is also PNG.

But, when i build the ISO and run on VirtualBOX, the image is not loaded, looking like that. Being with this blue background.

[image]

I also tried to edit the `/usr/share/gnome-background-properties/ubuntu-wallpapers.xml` changing the `<filename>` to other image, and i copied this image to the `/usr/share/backgrounds`, but still not working.

When i install the system on the VM, and i tried to open the image the follow error appears:

[image]

Someone have this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try renaming your custom image to the original image's filename.  For example, if the original was `blahblah.png` save your image as `blahblah.png` with the ***same exact permissions***.

That should do the trick without any additional hacking.

Comment: Hey bro, thank you so much. The image that i copy haven't the read permission for Others and Group